# Error while installing Oracle JDK 8 in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: apt, java, dpkg, jdk

These commands both run successfully

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

But when I run `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`, it downloads the  JDK but then stops showing the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
  subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Edit your question an add the output of `uname -a`

Answer (score -2):

Open terminal and run the following commands,

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/\*.\*` 
sudo apt-get clean`
sudo apt-get install -f`
sudo apt-get update`
```

Comment: It would have been better/safer for the user, if you had explained what the commands do, what output could be expected in case of success or failure.

Comment: Using 'install -f' should be considered as a last resort

Comment: I still get that error after applying this